# Should SSO Request Bindings match between an SP and IdP?

Tags: single-sign-on, saml-2.0

In an SP-initated single sign-on setup, can an SP be configured to send SSO Requests using HTTP Redirect binding, while its IdP is configured to send HTTP POst?

Any pitfalls?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, an SP can send SSO Requests using the HTTP Redirect binding as long as the IDP is configured to receive those requests over that binding. Separately and IDP can send SSO Responses over any binding that it wants to including HTTP Post as long as the SP is able to deal with that binding.

No pitfalls, the binding used to send SSO requests from SP to IDP is independent from the binding used for HTTP Responses from IDP to SP.